# perl and excel graph axes

Tags: perl, excel, graph, scale, win32ole

I'm fiddling with excel graphs created in a perl script and trying to set minimum and maximum axes however I don't seem to be able to get my head around the VBA to Perl Conversion.

Please can you help.

I have tried this a few different ways, but here is what I have now.

```
   $chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory)->MinorUnit => 0;
   $chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory)->MajorUnit => 100;
```

I have also tried the following.

```
   $chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory)->MinimumScale => 0;
   $chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory)->MaximumScale => 100;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Micro

Comment: What module are you using for Excel?

Comment: I'm trying to use the basic modules. So Win32 OLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching and some trial and error I managed to sort this one out. The required code was as follows.

For the x axis;

```
$chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory,xlPrimary)->{MinimumScale} = 0;
$chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlCategory,xlPrimary)->{MaximumScale} = 100;
```

And For the y axis;

```
$chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlValue,xlPrimary)->{MinimumScale} = 0;
$chart1->{Chart}->Axes(xlValue,xlPrimary)->{MaximumScale} = 100;
```